# Multiple Blazored Typeaheads within foreach

Tags: c#, blazor-server-side

I'm using Blazored Typeahead within my Blazor server application.
In my razor page following code

#### Blazored Typeahead - within Foreach

```
@foreach (var employee in EmployeeList)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="@GetPeopleLocal"
                           @bind-Value="@SelectedPerson"
                           placeholder="Search by first name...">
                <SelectedTemplate Context="person">
                    @person.Firstname
                </SelectedTemplate>
                <ResultTemplate Context="person">
                    @person.Firstname @person.Lastname
                </ResultTemplate>
            </BlazoredTypeahead>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="@GetRolesLocal"
                           @bind-Value="@SelectedRole"
                           placeholder="Search by role name...">
                <SelectedTemplate Context="role">
                    @role.Rolename
                </SelectedTemplate>
                <ResultTemplate Context="role">
                    @role.Rolename
                </ResultTemplate>
            </BlazoredTypeahead>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(()=>OnEmployeeDelete(employee))">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}

    <div class="form-group">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@(()=>OnEmployeeAdd())">Add Employee</a>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="@(()=>CreateEmployeeList())">Create Employee List</a>
    </div>


@code {
    private List<Employee> EmployeeList = new List<Employee>();
    private Employee employee = new Employee();

    private List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
    private List<Role> Roles = new List<Role>();
    private Person SelectedPerson;
    private Role SelectedRole;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        People.AddRange(new List<Person>()
            {
                    new Person() { Id = 1, Firstname = "Martelle", Lastname = "Cullon" },
                    new Person() { Id = 2, Firstname = "Zelda", Lastname = "Abrahamsson" },
                    new Person() { Id = 3, Firstname = "Benedetta", Lastname = "Posse" },
                    new Person() { Id = 4, Firstname = "Benoite", Lastname = "Gobel" },
                    new Person() { Id = 5, Firstname = "Charlot", Lastname = "Fullicks" },
                    new Person() { Id = 6, Firstname = "Vinson", Lastname = "Turbat" },
                    new Person() { Id = 7, Firstname = "Lenore", Lastname = "Malam" },
                    new Person() { Id = 8, Firstname = "Emanuele", Lastname = "Kolakovic" }
                });
        Roles.AddRange(new List<Role>()
            {
                    new Role() { Id = 1, Rolename = "Programmer Frontend" },
                    new Role() { Id = 1, Rolename = "Programmer Backend" },
                    new Role() { Id = 2, Rolename = "UX Designer" },
                    new Role() { Id = 3, Rolename = "DBA Developer" }
                });
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPeopleLocal(string searchText)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(People.Where(x => x.Firstname.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())).ToList());
    }

    private async Task<IEnumerable<Role>> GetRolesLocal(string searchText)
    {
        return await Task.FromResult(Roles.Where(x => x.Rolename.ToLower().Contains(searchText.ToLower())).ToList());
    }

    public void OnEmployeeDelete(Employee employee)
    {
        EmployeeList.Remove(employee);
    }

    public void OnEmployeeAdd()
    {
        EmployeeList.Add(new Employee());
    }

    private async Task CreateEmployeeList()
    {
        foreach (var employee in EmployeeList)
        {
            var resultPerson = employee.Person;
            var resultRole = employee.Role;
        }
    }
}
```

[image: screen shoot of application]

My problem is when I add a new row by clicking "Add Employee" and choose some value for name and role (e.g. Samara and Developer .NET) then all row gets the same values.

Furthermore when I click the "Create Employee List" button which calls the `CreateEmployeeList` method then `EmployeeList` has null values in all rows.

And when trying to delete a row the method `OnEmployeeDelete` removes the last row, regardless of which row I clicked.

The `Employee` class:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public Employee() { }
    public Employee(Person person, Role role)
    {
        Person = person;
        Role = role;
    }

    public Person Person { get; set; }
    public Role Role { get; set; }
}
```

The `Role` class:

```cs
public class Role
{
    public Role() { }
    public Role(int id, string rolename)
    {
        Id = id;
        Rolename = rolename;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Rolename { get; set; }
}
```

Note I'm using the repo from Blazor Typeahead: https://github.com/Blazored/Typeahead

I have just created a page Foreach.razor and added above code to it.

Comment: You are sharing `@SelectedPerson` and `@SelectedRole` for each element in `EmployeeList`.

Comment: Just I am thinking that how to arrange your logic. Maybe you shouldn't use `EmployeeList` for the `foreach`, but you need to declare a variable: `SelectedEmployeeList` and use for the `foreach`.

Comment: I'm aware that using SelectedPerson and Role for every row causes the rows to have same values, however I can't see how to have unique selectedperson and role objects 
 for every row.

Comment: Same way you've done "the user chooses how many things to enter" since Computing 101 class; you need a collection of objects to represent your rows and hold your selection, not a single variable like `private Person SelectedPerson;`  or `private Role SelectedRole;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the attached code, `@SelectedPerson` and `@SelectedRole` are shared for each element in `EmployeeList`. That is why changing `@SelectedPerson` or `@SelectedRole` in a row will reflect in the other elements.

You need a variable to hold the selected employee list.

```
@foreach (var selectedEmployee in SelectedEmployeeList)
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3">
            <BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="@GetPeopleLocal"
                           @bind-Value="@selectedEmployee.Person"
                           placeholder="Search by first name...">
                <SelectedTemplate Context="person">
                    @person.Firstname
                </SelectedTemplate>
                <ResultTemplate Context="person">
                    @person.Firstname @person.Lastname
                </ResultTemplate>
            </BlazoredTypeahead>
        </div>
        <div class="col-3">
            <BlazoredTypeahead SearchMethod="@GetRolesLocal"
                           @bind-Value="@selectedEmployee.Role"
                           placeholder="Search by role name...">
                <SelectedTemplate Context="role">
                    @role.Rolename
                </SelectedTemplate>
                <ResultTemplate Context="role">
                    @role.Rolename
                </ResultTemplate>
            </BlazoredTypeahead>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-danger" @onclick="@(()=>OnEmployeeDelete(selectedEmployee))">X</a>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

```cs
private List<Employee> SelectedEmployeeList = new List<Employee>();

public void OnEmployeeDelete(Employee employee)
{
    SelectedEmployeeList.Remove(employee);
}

public void OnEmployeeAdd()
{
    SelectedEmployeeList.Add(new Employee());
}

private async Task CreateEmployeeList()
{
    foreach (var employee in EmployeeList)
    {
        SelectedEmployeeList.Add(new Employee { Person = employee.Person, Role = employee.Role });
    }
}
```